# cx_Oracle high memory use

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, memory

I am using cx_Oracle with python to select a dataset of about 200,000 rows.

I am having memory issues with my application, so I am memory profiling. The memory use for these lines is over 1G, however, the actual data returned into list (I used pickle to get the size), was only about 100MB.

What am I missing here? I would expect it to be 100MB or at most 200MB if I am copying over the data from memory when I create the list.
Thanks.

```
cx = cx_Oracle.connect(x,y,z)
c = cx.cursor()
l=[]
c.arraysize=1000
results = c.execute(query)
for row in results:
    l.push(row)
```

Comment: what version of oracle?

Comment: oracle 11 .....